# Can I set session variables for Postgres from the JDBC Connection

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

For performance reasons, I'm trying to limit the round trips I make to the database. Currently I connect and the issue a series of statements like `SET TIMEZONE='America/New_York'` to postgres. Many databases allow session variables and similar settings to be passed to the database either as part of the jdbc url i.e. `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/test?timezone=America/New_York` or by adding the it to the property list like this...

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test:5435";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user","fred");
props.setProperty("password","secret");
props.setProperty("timezone","America/New_York");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

I can't find definitive information if this is supported by postgres and tests have failed.

Comment: "*a series of statements like*" - you can send all those queries in a single roundtrip if you delimit them with `;`. Although the JDBC specification does not allow running multiple statements with a single `execute()` call, the Postgres JDBC driver does support that, e.g. `stmt.execute("set timezone='...'; set work_mem='64MB'; set ...;")`

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters) says:

> Connection Parameters
>
> [...]
>
> - **options** = String
>
> Specify 'options' connection initialization parameter.
>
> The value of this property may contain spaces or other special characters, and it should be properly encoded if provided in the connection URL. Spaces are considered to separate command-line arguments, unless escaped with a backslash (`\`); `\\` represents a literal backslash.

So you should use

```java
props.setProperty("options", "-c timezone=America/New_York");
```

Comment: It wasn't clear what is valid there from the docs. But when I tried it I get `PSQLException: FATAL: invalid command-line argument for server process: timezone=UTC`

Comment: Setting options to `-c timezone=America/New_York` is accepted without error but doesn't actually do anything for the session.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware that you need the `-c` as well. Perhaps the value is overridden later? Log the SQL statements on the PostgreSQL server and see.